# Java 2d Array Logic Error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

UPDATE AT BOTTOM:

I am creating a program with a 2d array. The array has 26 rows, and 26 columns. I am searching, one line at a time, for case-insensitive two-letter pairs, such as: "AA","AB","AC","AD", etc. If I find a letter pair, I add one to it's corresponding index in the array. The first letter determines the row, and second letter determines the column. For example this is how it is supposed to run:

```
aa
ab
ac
ad
ba
bb
bc
za
zb
zc
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

My program is able to do above, however when I input:

```
AABBAACCAA
AA
4 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want the upper-left most number that currently says 4, to say 2. In other words, I want any particular letter pair to be *only counted once per line*. So If I input AAAAAAAAAAA, I want to *only add one* to alphabet[0][0]
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Freq{
    private static final int ROWS = 26;
    private static final int COLS = 26;
    private static int[] [] alphabet = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(userInput.hasNextLine()) {
            line = userInput.nextLine();
            processLine(line);

        }
        printArray();

    }
    public static void processLine(String line) {
        line = line.toUpperCase();
        for(int a = 0; a < line.length() - 1; a++) {
            char firstLetter = line.charAt(a);
            char secondLetter = line.charAt(a + 1);
            alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] += 1;

        }
    }
    public static void printArray() {
    for (int b = 0; b < alphabet.length; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < alphabet[b].length; c++){
            System.out.print(alphabet[b][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
UPDATE: The top row of my array represents these two-letter pairs:

AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN AO AP AQ AR AS AT AU AV AW AX AY AZ

The second row represents these two-letter pairs:
BA BB BC BD BE BF BG BH BI BJ BK BL BM BN BO BP BQ BR BS BT BU BV BW BX BY BZ

etc.
The string: "This is a test" has these letter pairs: TH, HI, IS, IS, TE, ES, ST. These are all the letter pair occurrences in that string. However, I want to count each letter pair only once, so for my purposes, I want to record that string as having these letter pairs: TH, HI, IS, TE, ES, ST. Note the IS is not listed twice as I am only looking for one occurrence *per line of input*

This means if I enter on **one line**:

AAAAAAAAAAAA

I only want to add 1 to the first element in my array. So I would want the top row of my array to look like this:

1 0 0 0 0 0 0...

**However**, if I input the string "AAAAAAAAAAAA" on multiple lines like this:

AA
AA
AA
AA
AA
AA
AA

Then I want to add 6 to the first element of my array. *Because AA occurred 6 different times on 6 different lines* So I would want the top row of my array to look like this:

6 0 0 0 0 0 0...

Comment: An array might not be a good choice here, because the width is fixed, and in practice you don't know how many matches you will end up having.

Comment: The width doesn't need to be variable. All I'm doing is adding to an element of an array. I don't need to create more indices based on how many matches I find. If I find a match, I simply add one to it's corresponding element. The thing I don't know how to do, is if I have more than one occurrence on a line, I just want to add one, not more than one.

Comment: I gave you an answer below which I think should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following implementation adds a two dimensional boolean array called `visited` which keeps track of whether a given pair of letters has been seen *for the current line*.  If we come across a pair of letters, for a given line, which we have not seen before, then we add one to the total for that cell.  But seeing the same pair again in the current line will be ignored and the total won't move up.  After consuming each line, we reset the `visited` array to false for every pair so that it can be reused with the proceeding line.

```
public class Freq {
    private static final int ROWS = 26;
    private static final int COLS = 26;
    private static int[][] alphabet = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    private static boolean[][] visited = new boolean[ROWS][COLS];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (userInput.hasNextLine()) {
            clearVisited();
            line = userInput.nextLine();
            processLine(line);
        }
        printArray();
    }

    public static void clearVisited() {
        for (int r=0; r < visited.length; r++) {
            for (int c=0; c < visited[r].length; c++){
                visited[r][c] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void processLine(String line) {
        line = line.toUpperCase();
        for (int i=0; i < line.length()-1; i++) {
            char firstLetter = line.charAt(i);
            char secondLetter = line.charAt(i + 1);
            if (!visited[firstLetter-65][secondLetter-65]) {
                alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] += 1;
                visited[firstLetter-65][secondLetter-65] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just put a condition in here:**

```
for (int a=0; a < line.length() - 1; a++) {
    char firstLetter = line.charAt(a);
    char secondLetter = line.charAt(a + 1);
    if (alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] == 0) { // Put it here
        alphabet[firstLetter - 65][secondLetter - 65] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: please put a check in my answer if it is right to help other. thank you!

Comment: But then If i input: "AA", "AA",  and "AABBAA" on three different lines, I still only have a value of one in my first element, but I need to have a value of 3.

Comment: Should I ask the question again to see if anyone else replies?

Comment: @T.Dog No, you should _clarify_ exactly what you are trying to do here, by showing us several examples of sample input and output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just updated the question at the bottom. I'm very sorry for the confusion and I appreciate your time.